# how to calculate the number of columns in a database with specific values (Query)

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, chart.js

I have a table tbl_student and table year, where students take the school year from the year table.

here the tbl_student :

```
|id_st   | student_name  |  year  | status |
--------------------------------------------
| 501    | John Carlton  |   1    |    1   |
--------------------------------------------
| 502    | Harold Louis  |   2    |    1   |
--------------------------------------------
| 503    | Jackson F     |   2    |    0   |
--------------------------------------------
```

and here the tbl_year :

```
|id_year | year_name | 
----------------------
| 1      | 2001      |
----------------------   
| 2      | 2002      |
----------------------  
| 3      | 2003      |
----------------------
```

what I want is that I can count the number of active students (with column status values = 1) every year, I have tried to calculate it with my query but what I get is counting the number of students per year, here is my current query :

public function getStudentActive(){

```
    $sql = "SELECT b.year_name as year, count(a.status=1) as total from tbl_student as a left join tbl_year as b on b.id_year=a.year GROUP BY a.tbl_year ORDER BY year ASC" ;
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}
```

but the result is that the query still counts the total number of students per year, all I want is that I can calculate value 1 in the status column in the student table .

Your help will mean a lot to me, thank you! And sorry if the writing of my question is not neat and sorry for my bad English ... with love ~ John Harold.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are `COUNT`ing a boolean expression: `a.status=1` which will always count 1 (unless `a.status` is null), regardless of whether the expression is true or false. Instead of `COUNT`ing those values, `SUM` them instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT b.year_name as year, SUM(a.status=1) as total 
        from tbl_student as a 
        left join tbl_year as b on b.id_year=a.year
        GROUP BY a.tbl_year 
        ORDER BY year ASC" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your student table just has 1&0 status, the sum value of the status column is just your desired result which is the number of active students every year.like below:

```
select
    a.year_name,
    sum(b.status) as active_student_count
from
    tbl_year a
left join
    tbl_student b on a.id_year = b.year
group by
    a.year_name
```

And if your student status is not just only two values, and also has other status such as 2,3,4...and only 1 represent the active status, you can use the "case when" expresions in your SQL, like below:

```
select
    a.year_name,
    sum(case when b.status=1 then 1 else 0 end) as active_student_count
from
    tbl_year a
left join
    tbl_student b on a.id_year = b.year
group by
    a.year_name
```

Just hope it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

## In the controller add this code:

```
$activeStudents = $this->student_model->count_student_active(array('status'=>1);
```

## Add this code in student_model:

```
public function count_student_active($where)
   {

       $this->db->select();

       $this->db->from('tbl_student');

       $query = $this->db->get_where('', $where);

       $result = $query->num_rows();

       return $result;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*),year.year_name FROM `student` INNER JOIN year on student.year = year.id where student.status = '1' GROUP BY student.year" ;
return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
```

Comment: Do not post code only answers on StackOverflow. Include explanation along with the code. This will be helpful for the future visitors.